# hibernate SQLQueryImpl setParameter vs setString

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

We are having trouble figuring out why using setParameter on executeUpdate queries are slower compared to using setString, setLong.

```
  SQLQueryImpl query = session.createSQLQuery("update message set status = :status where attempt_id = :attemptId")
```

Whenever I use:

```
query.setParameter("status", Status.DONE)
query.setParameter("attemptId", id)
```

It resolves almost 10x slower as compared to using:

```
query.setString("status", Status.DONE.toString())
query.setLong("attemptId", id)
```

I can verify that they have similar queries generated underneath:

```
update message set status = ? where attempt_id = ?
```

Why is setParameter() slower?

Is using setString(), setLong() preferred over using setParameter()

I thought it just adds a layer that figures out what type to add but should be almost the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A check of the source code for [AbstractQueryImpl](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.15.Final/org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl.java#AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) will reveal why. In short, it has to figure out what `Type` of parameter you are setting, which is expensive (and wasteful since you should know what you are injecting).

```
public Query setParameter(String name, Object val) throws HibernateException {
    if (val == null) {
        Type type = parameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType( name );
        if ( type == null ) {
            type = StandardBasicTypes.SERIALIZABLE;
        }
        setParameter( name, val, type );
    }
    else {
        // determineType() method below is expensive
        setParameter( name, val, determineType( name, val ) );
    }
```

Compare now to `setString()`, which doesn't have to determine the `Type` and explicitly sets it instead:

```
public Query setString(int position, String val) {
    setParameter(position, val, StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
    return this;
}
```

Using `setString` or `setLong` also is more strictly-typed per the method signature, which is generally what you want (better to fail at compile time than runtime).